# How to real time replace text with emoticons in my php comment box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my comment box I want to If user write :) or :( or something like any emotion in textarea, It replace emoticon just after click on space key.

So, how to real time replace my text to emoticons.

my php code: which replace emoticon after submit.

```
function smileys($text){
// Smiley to image
$smileys = array(
    ':)' => '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':D' => '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':(' => '<img src="smilies/sad.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
);

// Now you need find and replace
foreach($smileys as $search => $replace){
     $text = preg_replace("#(?<=\s|^)" . preg_quote($search) . "#", $replace, $text);
return $text;
    }
}

echo''.smileys($description).'';
```

Comment: What do you mean with realtime? Use javascript to replace it client-Side if you want an immediately replacement

Comment: realtime mean just in time to user write text on comment box. How to use javascript to replace it client-Side please.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a JavaScript solution like this one: https://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea